# Can we add CA trusted root to certificate without a CSR (certificate signed request)

Tags: ssl, keystore, csr, self-signed-certificate

I'm new to SSL certificate. I understand the following premise
"
The Certificate Signing Request (CSR) is a tool for including a third party in the certificate creation process without divulging your private key. Its essentially a packet of encoded information (including the public key) which can be sent to the third party for signing. The third party receives the CSR, signs it with their intermediate or root certificate, and send back the certificate to you. Your new and shiny certificate file is now a keypair with your private key file. Even better, the third party never had access to your private key through the entire process.

1 I create a key store
2 Generate a public and private key pair in it.
3 Generate a CSR.
4 Submit the CSR and get Certificate and Trust Chain.
5 I import the Certificate
6 I must import Trust Chain

I'm using a keytool and trying to generate a key pair with a signed CA issuer. I want to know if this can only be accomplished via a CSR.

Comment: "trying to generate a signed certificate" to do that you need the private key of the CA that will sign this certificate. Which means basically that you run this specific CA. As for your title: no, to import a CA you just import its public certificate in your trust store. Since it includes its public key this is enough to verify any certificate signed by it. But of course you can not sign yourself any certificate on behalf of it. Also, as it stands your question is not about programming and hence is offtopic here.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you for your response. I get it now